# Pulling data from one table to use in another query for SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm in the process of learning SQL Server, and so I'm not quite sure what the proper terms to search for something like this are.

I have two tables, `People` (ID, FirstName, LastName, Job):

```
ID   FirstName LastName   Job
 1     Barack    Obama    Null  // Obama is unemployed
```

and `Companies` (ID, CompanyName, City, State):

```
ID   CompanyName           City        State
 1   Legislative Branch    Washington   DC
 2   Executive Branch      Washington   DC
 3   Judicial Branch       Washington   DC
```

I know I can run something like

```
update Persons 
set Job = '2' 
where ID = 1;
```

to do that manually, but that requires me to know that Executive Branch's ID is 2.

How would I write a query that looks up `CompanyName == 'Executive Branch'` in the `Companies` table then uses the `ID` from there?

```
ID   FirstName LastName   Job
----------------------------------
 1     Barack    Obama     2  //Obama now works for the Executive Branch
```

Possibly related, is it considered "bad form" to use `ID` for both of those tables, or should one be `PersonID` and the other `CompanyID`?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not really following the `Job` column. So, the `ID` from `People` should be the same as the `ID` in companies?, and then you want to update that very same `ID` to the `Job` column?

Comment: The Job column should contain the ID of the company where the person works.  I'll update the question to be more clear.

Comment: and how are we supposed to know the company where a person works?

Comment: I'm a nearly-absolute-beginner at SQL Server.  For the purposes of the question, it's what I (the query-writer) know, but want to change the database to reflect that.

Comment: @Benjin - where did you get this example from ?

Comment: Came up with it myself.  If it were from a specific resource, I'm sure it'd have the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How would I write a query that looks up CompanyName == 'US Gov' in the Companies table then uses the ID from there?

As simple as:

```
SELECT ID
FROM Companies
WHERE CompanyName = 'US Gov'
```

Added into your example:

```
UPDATE People
SET Job = (SELECT ID
           FROM Companies
           WHERE CompanyName = 'US Gov')
WHERE ID IN (id1, id2, id3, ..., idn)
```

being id1, id2, etc the IDs of the people you want to modify.

Comment: This looks to be exactly what I wanted.  Not knowing that I could embed a SELECT inside another query was the missing piece.  Thanks!

Comment: If it's the correct answer, do not forget to add it as a correct answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand on your post your trying to update the job field to the corresponding ID field on the other table. If so, you would do something like this:

```
UPDATE People p
SET
   p.job = c.id
FROM
   p
INNER JOIN
   Companies c
ON p.id = c.id
WHERE
   c.id = 1;
```

Comment: This is the exact answer I posted, but I deleted it because as @Lamak points out in the comments, it appears that OP wants to join  the table on JOB.. not ID

Comment: Even if the syntax is correct, the logic behind it doesn't make sense. In this scenario, the `JOIN` is absolutely not necessary, since it could simply update the value of the `People` `ID`

Comment: @paqogomez Yeah, I see what he says now. However that doesn't make any sense as CompanyName doesn't exist in the people column.

Comment: @Arun Exactly, the requirements, as currently written, don't really make much sense

Comment: I've updated the question with a more complete example and some comments.  I hope it makes sense now.

Comment: @Benjin You can add a subquery inside the WHERE clause. so WHERE (SELECT whatever from whatever where whatever=blah) http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189575(v=sql.105).aspx